# Algebraic expansion with complex variable...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I expand the following

$$ \big||y| - x \big|^2 $$

note that $|.|$ means magnitude of complex variable and $x$ is complex variable..

Is the solution

$$ \big||y| - x \big|^2 = \big(|y| - x \big)^2= |y|^2+|x|^2-2 |y|x$$

My other question is the following inequality true?

$$ x \geq |x| $$ always?

Thanks

Comment: abstract-algebra is a different subject. Please read the blurbs of the tags before using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inequalities do not make sense for complex numbers (what would it mean to say $i \geq |i| = 1$?) Further, this isn't even true for real numbers: $-1 \leq |-1|$ (in fact the opposite is true for real numbers: $r \leq |r|$).

With regard to your first question, no that is not a solution. The critical error is that, for a complex number $|x|^2 \neq x^2$ in general. What is true is that

$$
|x|^2 = x\overline x,
$$

i.e. if $x = u + iv$ then

$$|x|^2 = (u + iv)(u-iv) = u^2 + iuv - iuv - i^2v^2 = u^2 + v^2.
$$

So, to carefully write out your expression (assuming $y$ is real, and $x = u + iv$ is complex, and let $c = |y|$ to save me writing absolute values over and over):

$$
||y| -x|^2 = |c - u - iv|^2 = ((c - u) - iv)\overline{((c - u) - iv)} \\
= ((c - u) - iv)((c - u) + iv) = (c - u)^2 + v^2 = c^2 -2uc + u^2 + v^2 \\
= |y|^2 - 2|y|\textrm{Re}(x) + |x|^2.
$$

If $y$ is meant to be complex, write $y = s + it$, note $|y| = \sqrt{s^2 + t^2}$ and then proceed carefully.

Comment: for second question, do you agree that $||x|-|y|| \le |x-y|$ is true? if yes than why is it that my second question is false?

Comment: With regard to $|x|^2 \neq x^2$, this error is made in the very first step, when you write $||y| - x|^2 = (|y| - x)^2$.

Comment: is in general $||y|-x|^2 \neq (|y|-x)^2$?

Comment: That is correct. let $y = 0$, $x = i$, then $||y| - i|^2 = |-i|^2 = 1^2 = 1$, but $(|y| - x)^2 = (-i)^2 = -1$.

Comment: thank you very much, Do you agree that $||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|$?

Comment: It **is** true that $||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y|$. This is a consequence of the triangle inequality: $|x| = |x - y + y| \leq |x - y| + |y|$ so $|x| - |y| \leq |x - y|$. Similarly, $|y| \leq |x - y| + |x|$, showing $||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y|$.

Comment: Thank you alot, you have been very helpful, one last question if you don't mind, assuming $x$ is complex, can the following product be simplified: $F= |x|\text{ Re}(x)$ ?

Comment: so this quantity $|x| \text{Re}(x) $ is it always positive?

Comment: Augh, no, I was careless there. If $u < 0$ then $u \neq \sqrt u^2$ so what I wrote isn't valid. There's not really a better way to write $|x|\textrm{Re}(x)$.

Comment: @Henry if we are consistent with the ordering axioms of real numbers (safe to assume I feel), then there is no such ordering relation possible in the complex plane. I recommend Jerrold Marsden's "Basic Complex Analysis" for reference.